# Relation between $a^c-b^c$ and $(a-b)^c$ when $1\geq b\geq a\geq 0$ and $c>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

How can I determine if  $a^c-b^c\geq(a-b)^c$ or $a^c-b^c<(a-b)^c$ when $1\geq b\geq a\geq 0$ and the expoent is some $c\in(0,2)$?

The relation is trivial if $c=1$. What if $c>1$ or $c<1?$

Comment: Can you check the inequality? Do you want $a^ c - b^c$ or $b^c - a^c$? For the former, you should be able to show that $ a^c - b^c < 0 < (a-b)^c$.

Comment: I want $a^c-b^c$. I was thinking  of how to show $0<(a-b)^c$.

Comment: Oh wait, I screwed that up too. In general, (esp when the exponent is a real non-rational number), you'd want the base to be positive. (I made that assumption, hence my screwup).

Comment: The upper bound $a\le b \le 1$ doesn’t matter, since you could divide both numbers by the same positive number without changing the inequality.

Comment: $a-b$ can't be positive and therefore when $a-b$ is negative, this question doesn't make sense at $c=\frac 12,\frac 32$ for example.

Comment: @Koro,maybe $b\geq a$is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb R$, this question doesn't make sense. 
Note that $(a-b)\lt 0$, if $a\ne b$ and therefore for non integral $c\in (0,2)$, 
$(a-b)^c=(b-a)^c (-1)^c=(b-a)^c \exp (ic(2n\pi+\pi/2))$, $n=0,\pm 1, \pm 2,\cdots $ and therefore $\lt $ or $\gt $ don't make sense.